# Java Client/Server Socket Broken Pipe

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I'm creating an update client via Sockets and I'm getting a Broken Pipe on the server side.  The server accepts a client socket and responds to the same socket with either a message or a large byte array (~180MB).  The error does not happen when testing locally (both client and server on the same machine) and it seems that it happens while sending the byte array. I'm not specifying a time out on the client socket and don't know why it is closing before reading the full response.  Its my first time working with sockets and any help would be appreciated.

My Client Socket Code:

```
public static Response makeRequest(Request req) throws IOException {
        Response response = null;
        Socket echoSocket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;


            echoSocket = new Socket(serverHost, 10008);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(
                    echoSocket.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));



        out.writeObject(req);
        try {
            response = (Response)in.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       


        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        echoSocket.close();
        return response;
    }
```

Response is just a POJO holding the response (string/byte[] and other data)

My Server Code (copied an example of Sun/Oracle site and added my code to it)

```
public class Server extends Thread {

    private Socket clientSocket;



    public Server(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        {
            System.out.println ("New Communication Thread Started");

            try { 

                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                Request request = null;
                try {
                    request = (Request)in.readObject();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                UpdateDAO dao = new UpdateDAO();
                ClientDAO cdao = new ClientDAO();
                Update update = null;
                Client client = null;
                Session s = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
                Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();

                if (request != null) {
                    client = cdao.getClient(request.getClientId());
                    LogItem log = new LogItem();
                    log.setClient(client);
                    log.setTimestamp(new Date());
                    log.setAction(request.getAction());

                    if (request.getResponse() != null) {
                        update = dao.getUpdate(request.getResponse().getUpdateId());
                    }

                    TaskContext ctx = new TaskContext(request, client, update, log);
                    System.out.println("Action: " + request.getAction().getDescription());
                    Task task = TaskFactory.getTask(request.getAction());
                    System.out.println(task.getClass().getName());
                    Response response = task.perform(ctx);



                    out.writeObject(response);

                    log.setClientTaskDescription(request.getMessage());
                    log.setUpdate(ctx.getUpdate());
                    dao.save(ctx.getLog());
                    if (ctx.getUpdate() != null) {
                        dao.update(ctx.getUpdate());
                    }

                } else {
                    out.writeObject(new Response("what"));

                }

                t.commit();

                out.close(); 
                in.close(); 
                clientSocket.close(); 
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1); 
            } 
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 

        try { 
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10008); 

            System.out.println ("Connection Socket Created");
            try { 
                while (true)
                {
                    System.out.println ("Waiting for Connection");
                    new Server (serverSocket.accept()); 
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
                System.err.println("Accept failed."); 
                System.exit(1); 
            } 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 10008."); 
            System.exit(1); 
        } 
        finally
        {
            try {
                serverSocket.close(); 
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            { 
                System.err.println("Could not close port: 10008."); 
                System.exit(1); 
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Any chance the client is running out of memory?  Do you get an exception on the client side?

Comment: Can you post the full exception and trace?  Thanks

Comment: Gray, I always give credit where its deserved.  I only have posted 8 questions and answered several myself when received no answer/solution that does not solve my problem. The couple of questions I did get answer I did accept and thanked.  Client running out of memory! I should investigate that since I'm using the default memory settings on the client.  You might be absolutely right!

Answer (score 0):

If the client is, in fact, running out of memory:

```
java -Xmx512m -jar <the jar>
```

or

```
java -Xmx512m com.foo.blah.YourClass
```

would increase the maximum heap for the client/server. Keep in mind you may have to increase the heap for both sides of the pipe since both sides would be reading all ~180mb into memory at runtime.